# Is there a way to stop a command in a docker container

Tags: python, macos, docker, docker-machine

I have a docker container that is running a command. In the Dockerfile the last line is `CMD ["python", "myprogram.py"]` . This runs a flask server.

There are scenarios when I update `myprogram.py` and need to kill the command, transfer the updated `myprogram.py` file to the container, and execute `python myprogram.py` again. I imagine this to be a common scenario.

However, I haven't found a way to do this. Since this is the only command in the Dockerfile...I can't seem to kill it. from the containers terminal when I run `ps -aux` I can see that `python myprogram.py` is assigned a PID of 1. But when I try to kill it with `kill -9 1` it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a workaround to accomplish this? My goal is to be able to change `myprogram.py` on my host machine, transfer the updated `myprogram.py` into the container, and execute `python myprogram.py` again.

Comment: On my answer, I added the steps for a OSX/docker-machine usage according to what I remember. Please confirm if it works on your machine and report here if something's wrong, I'll try to correct if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use VOLUMES to mount your **myprogram.py** source code on your container, and just `docker stop` and `docker restart` the container.

**To make a VOLUME :**

add a **VOLUME** directive in your Dockerfile and rebuild your image :

```
VOLUME /path/to/mountpoint
```

and use the `-v` option when running your image.

```
docker run -d -v /path/to/dir/to/mount:/path/to/mountpoint myimage
```

**/!\ These steps above are enough only for a Linux environment. /!\**

To use it with something else (like Docker-machine on OSX), you must also make a mount point in the VM running Docker (probably virtualbox).

You'll have the following scheme :

`<Dir to share from your host (OSX)> <= (1) mounted on => <Mountpoint on VM> <= (2) mounted on => <Container mountpoint>`

The (2) is exactly like a Linux case (in fact, it IS a linux case).

The only step added is mounting the directory you want to share from your host on your VM.

**Here are the steps to mount the directory you want to share on the mountpoint in your VM, and then using it with your container :**

1- First stop the docker machine.

```
docker-machine stop <machine_name>
```

2- Add a sharedfolder to the VM.

```
VBoxManage sharedfolder add <machine_name> --name <mountpoint_name> --hostpath <dir_to_share>
```

3- Restart the docker machine :

```
docker-machine start <machine_name>
```

4- Creating the mountpoint with ssh and mounting the sharedfolder on it :

```
docker-machine ssh <machine_name> "sudo mkdir <mountpoint_in_vm>; sudo mount -t vboxsf <mountpoint_name> <mountpoint_in_vm>"
```

5- And then to mount the directory on your container, run :

```
docker run -d -v <mountpoint_in_vm>:</path/to/mountpoint (in the container)> myimage
```

**And to clean all this when you don't need it anymore :**

6- Unmount in VM :

```
docker-machine ssh <machine_name> "sudo umount <mountpoint_in_vm>; sudo rmdir <mountpoint_in_vm>"
```

7- Stop VM :

```
docker-machine stop <machine_name>
```

8- Remove shared folder :

```
VBoxManage sharedfolder remove <machine_name> --name <mountpoint_name>
```

Here is [a script](https://github.com/vmonteco/docker-rendu/blob/master/mission03/launch.sh) I made for studies purpose, feel free to use it if it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

> There are scenarios when I update myprogram.py and need to kill the
>   command, transfer the updated myprogram.py file to the container, and
>   execute python myprogram.py again. I imagine this to be a common
>   scenario.

Not really.  The common scenario is either:

- Kill existing container
- Build new image via your Dockerfile
- Boot container from new image

Or:

- Start container with a volume mount pointing at your source
- Restart the container when you update your code

Either one works.  The second is useful for development, since it has a slightly quicker turnaround.

Comment: Yes, this is for development. I understand that this wouldn't be a common scenario for a container running in production. Thanks, I'll start looking into how to mount volume.